# Abandoned cart Journey using data from Track Code

Tags: marketing-cloud, code, einstein-recommendations

In Marketing Cloud (SFMC) I used the track code to add cart and purchase.

How can I use the information about the abandoned cart in a Journey? Do I need to use any event?

I can see in Web analytics that has a number of abandoned carts, but the data extension "PI_ABANDONED_CART_ITEMS" is empty. Is it normal?

Answer (score 3):

*PI_ABANDONED_CART_ITEM* is not currently being used by the platform, and will not be populated with data if a cart is being abandoned. You will need to reach out to Salesforce to ask for a daily data dump with SKUs and uuids from abandoned carts. You will need to identify which fields from the catalogue are required in the CSV file, which will be placed on your Enhanced FTP once a day. You will need to build an automation importing these files to a Data Extension, and injecting contacts with abandoned carts into a journey. This is the only way you can link the collect codes with emails.

Comment: You can see the abandoned carts in web analytics though. Furthermore there is an abandoned cart journey as template. You can also see the current items of a subscriber when you navigate towards reporting inside Predictive web and search for a particular subscriber. You will see which items he has in his cart (even though he might have logged of). Therefore I believe that these informations are stored and can be used if there is an api for it (which I am not sure of). Maybe Lukas can dig a little bit deeper on the Salesforce side of things ;) looking forward to an extend of your post :P

Comment: Currently it requires a service engagement to build an audience file for abandon cart. Abandon cart information is not surfaced anywhere currently that can be actioned outside of this

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note on this one:

If you manage to have your e-commerce doing the job of flagging abandoned carts and sending the information over to SFMC using API call or even a CSV export to your SFTP, then surely a bit of AMP script can do the trick of using the information from your API call or CSV file and build a personalized email.

But if you're looking to a solution where SFMC will be in charge of flagging and collecting abandoned cart events happening on your e-commerce, then indeed you need to work with support to have some functionalities enabled in the back end.